# Capture image frames from Kinect and save to Hard drive

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, memory-leaks, kinect-sdk

My aim is to capture all the frames (RGB) from Kinect at 30 fps and save them to my hard drive. For doing this I took the following approach.

Get the frames from Kinect and store them in an array buffer. Since writing to disk (using `imwrite()`) takes a bit of time and I may miss some frames while doing so, so instead of directly saving them to the disk, I store them in an array. Now, I have another parallel thread that accesses this array and writes the individual frames to the disk as images.

Now I have used a static array of size 3000 and type `Mat`. This will suffice since I need to store frames for 1.5 minute videos (1.5 minutes = 2700 frames). I have declared the array as follows :

```
#define NUM_FRAMES 3000
Mat rgb[NUM_FRAMES];
```

I have already tested this limit by reading images and saving them to the array using the following code :

```
for(int i=0; i<NUM_FRAMES; i++)
{
   Mat img = imread("image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
   rgb[i] = img;
   imshow("Image", img);
   cvWaitKey(10);
}
```

The above code executed flawlessly.

But one problem is that the code I am using for capturing image using Kinect, captures the image in an `IplImage`. Thus I need to convert the image to `cv::Mat` format before using it. I convert it using the following command:

```
IplImage* color = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(COLOR_WIDTH, COLOR_HEIGHT), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
cvSetData(color, colorBuffer, colorLockedRect.Pitch); // colorBuffer and colorLockedRect.Pitch is something that Kinect uses. Not related to OpenCv
rgb[rgb_read++] = Mat(color, FLAG);
```

Now here lies my problem. Whenever I am setting `#define FLAG true`, it causes memory leaks and gives me `OpenCv Error: Insufficient memory (failed to allocate 1228804 bytes)` error.
But if I use `#define FLAG false` it works correctly, but the frames that I am getting is erroneous as shown below. They are three consecutive frames.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I was moving around my arm and the image got cut in between as can be seen from above.

Can someone please point out the reason for this weird behavior or any other alternate way of obtaining the desired result. I have been struggling with this since a few days now. Please ask for if any further clarifications are required.

I am using OpenCV 2.4.8, Kinect SDK for Windows version-1.8.0 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

Also can someone please explan to me the role of the `CopyData` parameter in `Mat::Mat`. I have already gone through [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat), but still it's not completely clear. Maybe that's why I could not solve the above error in the first place since it's working is not very clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, do *not* use IplImages, stick with cv::Mat, please.

the equivalent code for that would be:

```
Mat img_borrowed = Mat( height, width, CV_8U4C, colorBuffer, colorLockedRect.Pitch );
```

note, that this does not do any allocation on its own, it's still the kinect's pixels, so you will have to clone() it:

```
rgb[rgb_read++] = img_borrowed.clone();
```

this is the same as setting the flag in your code above to 'true'. (deep-copy the data)

[edit] maybe it's a good idea to skip the useless 4th channel (also less mem required), so , instead of the above you could do:

```
cvtColor( img_borrowed, rgb[rgb_read++], CV_BGRA2BGR); // will make a 'deep copy', too.
```

so, - here's the bummer: if you *don't* save a deep-copy in your array, you'll end up with garbled (and all the same!) images, probably even with undefined behaviour due to the locking/unlocking of the kinect buffer, if you *do* copy it (and you must), you will need *a lot* of memory.

unlikely, that you can keep 3000 *1024*786*4 = 9658368000 bytes in memory, you'll have to cut it down one way or another.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, sometimes I was even getting the same image copied over and again. Thanks a lot  for the reply. I will check if your stated method works. But why does the first piece of code, where I load 3000 images in an array, works so neatly ?

Comment: Oh ! I actually never saved the stored images back to disk to verify. Since it didn't give any memory leaks, I thought it was perfect. Thank you very much for the heads-up.

Comment: Yeah, now I get what's wrong. Maybe I need to cut down on my array limit or think of some other alternatives. It was so simple, even then it was killing me for a long time now. I will accept the answer. :)

Comment: do you need full-size images ? you could resize() them to half (4x more pics possible) or convert to bgr ( skip alpha, 1 channel less)

Comment: With full size I am getting close to 1200 images in my laptop. A parallel thread is writing as well. So if I use a circular queue, I may get a bit more, but that's not sufficient. As I said, I need close to 2700 frames. I will try by reducing either the frame size, or maybe take alternate frames instead of all the frames. Basically I have to find a trade-off.